# Longest alphabetical sequence in an alphanumeric password

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I generate the longest alphabetical sequence in an alphanumeric password?

So for example...

```
User ID: 1
Password: abcac734158a5d228b0597afccc907a3
Longest sequence: abc

User ID: 2 
Password: 2fe59c3c6cde3a53245fe223a3b6a838
Longest sequence: cde
```

It's unclear if they have to be sequentially alphabetical or just ordinally alphabetical.

I may be overthinking this, but my plan is to replace the numbers with spaces (using REPLACE, despite it not being terribly efficient in this case), and then try to use a function to separate the clumps of letters into rows (keeping them linked with the user ID). I've found some table-value functions that can parse sentences, but I'm still unclear about how to use them.

I'm also unfortunately still working in SQL 2008 R2, so I'm a bit more restricted than I would otherwise be.

Comment: Why is the second example `cd` and not `cde`? Why is the first example `abc` and not `abcac` or `afccc`?

Comment: This sounds more like a question you should pose to the person that set you this task.

Comment: Andrew, you're correct. I just made that change...I apologize! The only information I received is that it needs to be an alphabetical sequence (and was provided with those two examples). So I assume it's alphabetically sequential, rather than just whether or not the next letter in line is alphabetically after the one before it. This is in preparation for a job interview, so I'm limited in being able to contact someone to ask questions. This task is a little out of my league!